# Strategy for saving socket IDs and sending mesages to the right people

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, redis, socket.io

I'm creating a game (React Native +Node.js + SQL Server) where users are all members of a team. The team details and members are all stored in the database.

I'm planning on using socket.io to keep everybody in sync so when a player leaves a team for example a message needs to go to all their other team members to say they've left.

1) So, my first question is, once a user has connected and authenticated themselves is it a good strategy to store their socket ID in the database against the player so we can always look up the socket IDs of each player?

2) Second question is, how to get a list of team members and send message to all of them?

I can see that socket.io has the concept of "rooms", so I guess I could investigate  creating a room for each team and joining each player to the room, storing the room ID in the database etc. but I assume the room would still need to exist even if no players were online and I'd have to make sure I had a bulletproof way of subscribing and unsubscribing people from the rooms when they joined/left the team?

Second option would be to just get the list of team socket IDs from the database each time we need to send something to the team and loop through and send an individual message to each one. Is that terribly inefficient or is that what socket.io is doing under the hood anyway? Teams aren't the only examples of messages which will be sent in a group; when 3 teams are playing a game together I might have to send a message to everybody playing the game, so rooms might get complicated.

Bonus question: Should I give up and learn Redis and keep everything in memory, cutting out SQL server and just having all the teams, their members an socket IDs in Redis? I guess I'd still have the problem of keeping the DB and Redis in sync. The DB is the source of all truth when it comes to which player is in which team, so if the Redis store didn't know somebody had left a team we'd still keep sending messages to them.

Apologies for the rambling question.

Comment: I recently implemented a simple real time chat application using Angularjs, Nodejs and MongoDB. When a user was logging in, in the server's handle I was also saving an entry of the form <sockedID, userID> and <userID, socketID> (in two different dictionaries). Maybe this approach can give you an idea. I choose not to save it into the database to limit the updates there.

Comment: @adi Is that so you can do a quick lookup using either dictionary? Not sure it solves my wider problem, which is where to store what users are in which teams and how to send them a message. My hunch is that just keeping them where they are in the database will hammer the db, but copying them into Redis or subscribing them all to "rooms" might get out of sync and end up with the wrong messages going to the wrong people.

Comment: That depends whether the teams are permanent or not. For example, when a user would have created a group conversation in my app, I would create a new object in the database to represent this. This object contains the IDs of the users in that private conversation among the chat replies + some other metadata.

It really depends on how do you want to implement the whole thing.

Comment: Having a separate object for your 'team' concept is really helpful. Basically, when one of them must communicate with the others, the request will go to the server and you might ask the database who are the other members (or maybe use a cache). And since you are using that <id, socket> map, you'll instantly know where to send the messages :)

Comment: Yeah, I already have the team and members stored in the DB as the game wouldn't work without it. My question was really whether to get it from the DB every time to find out who to send it to, and whether to try to bend the "rooms" feature to do what I want or loop through the members myself sending single messages. Sorry, I know it's a lot of questions.

Comment: If you don't want to query the database each time, you may use another dictionary as a local cache (that will we invalidated after a period of time) or a Redis.